# Rename files and copy the renamed files to subbolder in main folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to rename files found in a main folder, but then put the renamed files in the same directory as the files to be copied.  This is my original folder structure:

```
Main Folder
    |
    |____file1.txt
    |____file2.txt
    |____file1.txt
```

I want to now create a folder under the Main Folder called "Renamed" and place the renamed files in there.  The new folder structure should look like this after successfully executing the code:

```
Main Folder
    |
    |____Renamed
    |      |
    |      |____renamed-file1.txt
    |      |____renamed-file2.txt
    |      |____renamed-file3.txt
    |
    |____file1.txt
    |____file2.txt
    |____file1.txt
```

However, in the code that I have so far, I cannot create the "Renamed" folder under the Main Folder as I get the error message `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument` that seem to occur at the line `fso.CopyFolder sItem, strPath2`.  Can you help me create the folder structure with the renamed folder and files.

Here is my code:

```
Sub RenameFile()
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strPath1 As String
    Dim strPath2 As String
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Dim z As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim V As Integer
    Dim TotalRow As Integer
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
      
    TotalRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
NextCode:
    strPath = sItem
    strPath2 = fso.BuildPath(sItem, "Renamed")
    ' Create the folder "Renamed"
    fso.CopyFolder sItem, strPath2
    
    For V = 1 To TotalRow
        
        ' Get value of each row in columns 1 start at row 2
        z = Cells(V + 1, 1).Value
        ' Get value of each row in columns 2 start at row 2
        s = Cells(V + 1, 2).Value
        
        Dim sOldPathName As String
        sOldPathName = fso.BuildPath(strPath2, z)
        sNewPathName = fso.BuildPath(strPath2, s)
        Name sOldPathName As sNewPathName
        On Error Resume Next
        Name sOldPathName As s
        
    Next V
    
    MsgBox "Congratulations! You have successfully renamed all the files"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: CopyFolder does not do what you think it does. It creates a copy of a folder in an existing folder. So your strPath2 should already exist for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy and Rename Files Using `Dir` and `FileCopy`

- Using [FileCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filecopy-statement) is much faster, simpler, and more straightforward: it copies and renames in one go.
- This is a simplified example to get you familiar with `Dir` and `FileCopy`. In your case, you would 'Dir' each name in column `A` and if the length of the filename is greater than 0 (confirming that the file exists), you would 'FileCopy the source path to the destination path (using the names in column `B`)'.

```vb
Sub RenameFiles()
    
    ' Source
    Const sFilePattern As String = "*.*"
    Dim sInitPath As String: sInitPath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    ' Destination
    Const dSubFolderName As String = "Renamed"
    Const dPrefix As String = "renamed-"
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .InitialFileName = sInitPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        sFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
      
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = sFolderPath & dSubFolderName & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir dFolderPath
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sFilePattern)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    On Error GoTo FileCopyError
        Do Until Len(sFileName) = 0
            FileCopy sFolderPath & sFileName, dFolderPath & dPrefix & sFileName
            sFileName = Dir
        Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    MsgBox "Congratulations! You have successfully renamed all the files.", _
        vbInformation
    
    Exit Sub
    
FileCopyError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description _
        & vbLf & "Could not copy '" & sFileName & "'."
    Resume Next

End Sub
```